# Help with integral manipulation

Tags: integration

So we have the following :
$$f(t,x) = {1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{{(x{e^{\sigma z\sqrt {T - t}  - (1/2){\sigma ^2}(T - t)}} - {K^*})}^ + }} {e^{ - {1 \over 2}{z^2}}}dz{\rm{ }}$$
for $t \in [0,T)$ and $x \in (0,\infty)$, let $l_t(x)$ be such that the integrand in $(2)$ is strictly positive if and only if $z > l_t(x)$ i.e;

$$l_t(x) = {\log {K^* \over x} \over {\sigma \sqrt {T - t} }} + {1 \over 2} \sigma \sqrt {T - t} $$

$$\phi (z) = {1 \over \sqrt {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^ze^{- {1 \over 2} u^2} du,\quad z \in ( - \infty ,\infty ) $$

Then for $t \in [0,T)$ and $x \in (0,\infty)$

$$f(t,x) = {x \over \sqrt {2\pi}} \int_{l_t(x)}^\infty {e^{\sigma z\sqrt {T - t}  - (1/2) \sigma ^2 (T - t) - (1/2){z^2}}} dz - {K \over \sqrt {2\pi } } \int_{l_t(x)}^\infty e^{ - {1 \over 2}z^2} dz \tag 3$$

$$ = {x \over \sqrt {2\pi} } \int_{l_t(x)}^\infty {e^{ - (1/2)(z - \sigma \sqrt {T - t} )^2}} dz - K^* \phi (-l_t(x)) $$

I dont understand in equation (3)how the changed the lower bound to $l_t(x)$ ? Should it not be $- \infty$ ? My next equation is that i dont see how $ \int\limits_{l_t(x)}^\infty e^{ - {1 \over 2} z^2} dz$ become $\phi ( -l_t(x))$ should it not be $ \phi (l_t(x))$?

Update: The last question should be fairly obvious if you change z for $l_t(x)$ in $$\phi (z) = {1 \over \sqrt {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^ze^{- {1 \over 2} u^2} du,\quad z \in ( - \infty ,\infty ) $$ and then *inverse* the values of the integral?

$  \int_{l_t(x)}^\infty e^{ - {1 \over 2}z^2} dz $

then  $ K^* \phi (-l_t(x)) $.
 Have i got that right ?